# If $a,b$ are roots for $x^2+3x+1=0$.Calculating $(\frac{a}{b+1})^2 +(\frac{b}{a+1})^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b$ are roots for the equation $x^2+3x+1=0$.How to calculate $$\left(\frac{a}{b+1}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{b}{a+1}\right)^2$$

Comment: hi, have you tried anything already? If so it would be useful to share what you have done so far.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because $x^2+3x+1=0$, we have $x^2=-3x-1$ and also $x^2+2x+1=-x$, for $x=a,b$. Hence $$\left(\frac{a}{b+1}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{(b+1)^2}=\frac{-3a-1}{-b}=\frac{3a+1}{b}$$
By symmetry, the desired expression is $$\frac{3a+1}{b}+\frac{3b+1}{a}=\frac{3a^2+a}{ab}+\frac{3b^2+b}{ab}=\frac{3a^2+a+3b^2+b}{ab}=\frac{3(-3a-1)+a+3(-3b-1)+b}{ab}=\frac{-8(a+b)-6}{ab}$$
Lastly, because $a,b$ are roots of $x^2+3x+1$, we know that $ab=1$ and $a+b=-3$.  Plugging this into our final expression gives $$\frac{-8(-3)-6}{1}=18$$

Comment: At least assuming that $a \not= b$. When this is not the case, the expression is equal to $3 + \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @vadim123: OP only assumed that $a$ and $b$ were roots; not that they were distinct.

Comment: Add.: The comment my last comment replied to is deleted so it doesn't really make sense any more.

Answer (score 18):

Hint: $(a+1)^2 + a = 0$ and so $\frac{1}{(a+1)^2} = -\frac{1}{a}$

Answer (score 4):

We note that the expression given is a symmetric rational function of the roots of the original polynomial, so can be expressed in terms of the coefficients of the original polynomial. We then use the basic facts we know about the sum and product of the roots, and the fact that both $a$ and $b$ satisfy the polynomial to achieve successive simplification of otherwise unwieldy terms. Here are some hints for a way through.

Note that $a+b=-3$ and $ab=1$ so that $(a+1)(b+1)=ab+(a+b)+1=-3+2=-1$

Use this to put the whole thing over a common denominator and simplify.

Note also that $a^2(a+1)^2=a^2(a^2+2a+1)=a^2(a^2+3a+1-a)=-a^3$

You might also need to use $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2-2ab$

---

Since the full answer closest in spirit to this has been deleted, note first $(a^2+b^2) = (-3)^2-2=7$. Then put the desired expression over common denominator $(a+1)^2(b+1)^2=1$ to obtain:$$a^2(a+1)^2+b^2(b+1)^2=-a^3-b^3=3(a^2+b^2)+(a+b)=21-3=18$$ [see comment for middle step]

Comment: Use also $-a^3=3a^2+a$ obtained from $a(a^2+3a+1)=0$

Comment: @MarkBennet:why is $ab=1$?

Comment: @Alex $(x-a)(x-b)=x^2+3x+1$ - expand and equate coefficients. This works because for $x=a$ or $x=b$ we have $(x-a)(x-b)=0$ - it is east to show that there is a unique monic quadratic equation which has roots $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @MarkBennet: thanks, that's great!

Answer (score 3):

$$a+b=-3,ab=1$$
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\implies a^2+b^2=7$$
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)\implies a^3+b^3=-18$$
$$(a^2+b^2)^2=a^4+b^4+2(ab)^2\implies a^4+b^4=47$$

$${\left(\dfrac {a}{b+1}\right)}^2+{\left(\dfrac {b}{a+1}\right)}^2$$
$$\dfrac {a^2(a+1)^2+b^2(b+1)^2}{((b+1)(a+1))^2}$$
$$\dfrac {a^4+2a^3+a^2+b^4+2b^3+b^2}{(ab+a+b+1)^2}$$
$$\dfrac {a^4+b^4+2(a^3+b^3)+a^2+b^2}{(1-3+1)^2}$$
$${47+2(-18)+7}$$
$$18$$

There is one alternate as in comment @mark suggest:
$$\dfrac {a^4+2a^3+a^2+b^4+2b^3+b^2}{(ab+a+b+1)^2}$$
$${a^4+3a^3+a^2-a^3+b^4+3b^3+b^2-b^3}$$
$${a^2(a^2+3a+1)-a^3+b^2(b^2+3b+1)-b^3}$$
since $a^2+3a+1=b^2+3b+10=0$
$$-a^3-b^3$$
$$18$$

Comment: @vadim123 I've edited my answer. I think now I'm clear to you.

Comment: Note that you can reduce the numerator to $-a^3-b^3$ quite easily using the original equation.

Comment: @MarkBennet in which line?

Comment: $a^4+2a^3+a^2=a^4+3a^3+a^2-a^3=a^2(a^2+3a+1)-a^3=a^3$ and the same for $b$ - 7th line I think. But it is also neat to know that you can calculate the higher powers if need be.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $ab=1, \frac a{b+1}=\frac{a}{\frac1a+1}=\frac{a^2}{a+1}=y$(say)

So, $a^2=y(a+1)$

and again $a^2+3a+1=0\implies a^2=-3a-1$

So, $ay+y=-3a-1\implies a=-\frac{y+1}{y+3} $

As $a$ is root of the given eqaution $$\left(-\frac{y+1}{y+3} \right)^2+3\left(-\frac{y+1}{y+3} \right)+1=0$$

Simply to get $y^2+4y-1=0$

Using Vieta's Formula, the required sum will be $(-4)^2-2(-1)=18$

Answer (score 1):

From the content of this thread follows,

$x^2 + 3x +1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x^2 +2x+1=-x \Leftrightarrow \boxed{(x+1)^2 =-x} (*)$ 

$\frac{a^2}{(b+1)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(a+1)^2}  \Leftrightarrow
\left(\frac{b^2}{b^2}\right)\frac{a^2}{(b+1)^2}+\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2}\right)\frac{b^2}{(a+1)^2} \\
\hspace{3.05cm}\Leftrightarrow \underset{\scriptsize -1 \, by \, (*)}{\boxed{\frac{b}{(b+1)^2}}}\frac{a^2
b}{b^2} + \underset{\scriptsize -1}{\boxed{\frac{a}{(a+1)^2}}}
\frac{b^2 a}{a^2} \\
\hspace{3.05cm}\Leftrightarrow  -\frac{a^2}{b}-\frac{b^2}{a}\\
\hspace{3.05cm}\Leftrightarrow \frac{- a^3 - b^3}{ab} \\
\hspace{3.05cm}\Leftrightarrow \boxed{- a^3 - b^3}$

$-a^3-b^3 = -(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab+2ab-2ab) \\
\hspace{1.85cm} = 3((a+b)^2-3ab)\\
\hspace{1.85cm} = 3(9-3) \\
\hspace{1.85cm} = \boxed{18}
$